# shifted screen with AMD card both drivers

Tags: linux, graphics, radeon, fglrx, amd

Running OS 12.3 i've encountered the problem of a ragged and/or shifted screen using an AMD HD 7670M and FGLRX and/or radeon drivers.

A full account can be found on:
[SuSE Hardware Forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/489376-ragged-shifted-screen-hd7670m-w-radeon-fglrx.html)

Short story: no matter what I do - the screen is either shifted to the right & wrapped (varying from 1/4 to 3/4 of monitor) or it appears in weird shifted stripes (varying in width between reboots).

Only thing that works is failsafe mode.

Any help would be much appreciated!
This is what I get when running get-edid:

```
./get-edid: get-edid version 2.0.0

Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
Function unsupported
Call failed

VBE version 0
VBE string at 0x0 "O"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
Report DDC capabilities

Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
Function unsupported
Call failed

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
Read EDID

Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
Function unsupported
Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
```

This is the force-converted output by parse-edid:

```
./parse-edid: parse-edid version 2.0.0
./parse-edid: EDID checksum failed - data is corrupt. Continuing anyway.
./parse-edid: first bytes don't match EDID version 1 header
./parse-edid: do not trust output (if any).

    # EDID version 105 revision 100
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "ZKD:3a20"
    VendorName "ZKD"
    ModelName "ZKD:3a20"
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:yes  Standby:no

    Mode    "1381x578"  # vfreq 134.753Hz, hfreq 87.185kHz
        DotClock    257.110000
        HTimings    1381 1496 1593 2949
        VTimings    578 632 644 647
    EndMode
    Mode    "1909x1824" # vfreq 24.545Hz, hfreq 96.217kHz
        DotClock    292.980000
        HTimings    1909 1958 2006 3045
        VTimings    1824 1826 1842 3920
    EndMode
    Mode    "1824x1853" # vfreq 7.869Hz, hfreq 31.073kHz
        DotClock    123.360000
    HTimings    1824 1872 1920 3970
        VTimings    1853 1891 1894 3949
    EndMode
Mode    "1902x1641" # vfreq 18.599Hz, hfreq 99.246kHz
        DotClock    300.220000
        HTimings    1902 1950 2067 3025
        VTimings    1641 1647 1709 5336
    EndMode
EndSection
```

Output of xrandr --prop w. fglrx nomodeset:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1600 x 1600
LVDS connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x  193mm
    SignalFormat:   DisplayPort
    ConnectorType:  Panel
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x768       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1024x600       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   800x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SignalFormat:   TMDS
ConnectorType:  HDMI
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SignalFormat:   VGA
ConnectorType:  VGA
```

Comment: Commenting out Modeline doesn't work? Have tried read-edid? http://polypux.org/projects/read-edid/

Comment: Modelines have been inserted by me (using cvt) and have partially improved the shifting problem (not the stripes though). Removing them does no good. Will try read-edid soon as I can.

Comment: Can you also post the output of `xrandr --prop`?

Comment: @Alex An error occurs when trying get-edid. 'xrand --prop' yields 'Can't open display'

Comment: Try xrandr when you are in safe mode, but probably you'll have the same EDID problem, as Xorg itself probably have. Your "SUSE paste" are expired but in one of them I remember a Modeline enumeration (maybe the flgrx) can you paste again somewhere?

Comment: @Alex Just kicked my install of fglrx, fallen back to radeon, still the same problem. Then reinstalled fglrx from OS repo, and started with nomodeset, the output of `xrandr --prop` is posted above. Read edid still fails.

Comment: Please paste the fglrx Xorg.0.log somewhere. With xrandr or with xorg.conf try to select a lower resolution from the given list, just width and height, "WxH". (Maybe the EDID is readable from the i2c bus only)

Comment: Here are the files:  [SUSEPaste](http://paste.opensuse.org/8010176)  and  [SUSEPaste](http://paste.opensuse.org/60089671)  also in the thread in OS-forums

Comment: You see? The Xorg seem to get the edid without problems and enumerate the available modes, try them from the higher to the lower

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10228/discussion-between-alex-and-nox)